# What is this tiny jumping cocoon?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this little jumpy cocoon thingie clinking approximately once every 4-5 seconds inside a metal lid. It's been jumping inside there for about a day since I first found it like that. It has a tiny flat mark on one of its sides which suggests that's how it initially stuck itself to something, and then got unstuck. What is this thing?

Here's a short web vid of it: https://giant.gfycat.com/IcyHarmfulCentipede.webm

And here's a static pic:

[image]

---

Update:

It stopped jumping around after about 1.5 days since I found it, and we decided to carefully cut it open with a paper knife. Inside was a white grub with a tiny orange dot on one of its ends, all foldy like a bendy part of a cocktail straw. It was still at first, but we sprayed it with water and put it on a leaf. It started moving around slowly, and looked like it was soaking up water. When we checked up on it later, it had disappeared and probably crawled away somewhere. Unfortunately, I didn't take any pictures of that, so it could have been anything.

Comment: excellent video!  I look forward to learning the answer.

Comment: @Will I posted an update.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: This was found in Russia, near Moscow.